# Antlr4 slow on RaspberryPi

Tags: python, parsing, raspberry-pi, antlr, antlr4

We are trying to parse a custom language on a RaspberryPi B with Antlr4 (Python2 target). However, it is way too slow to do anything serious: parsing a few lines takes around ten seconds. This is my code:

Transposeur.py:

```
# -*- coding:Utf-8 -*-

from antlr4 import *
from TransposeurLexer import TransposeurLexer
from TransposeurParser import TransposeurParser
import sys
from Listener import Listener

def transpose(file_path):

  input = FileStream(file_path)
  lexer = TransposeurLexer(input)
  stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
  parser = TransposeurParser(stream)
  tree = parser.myfile()
  listener = Listener()
  walker = ParseTreeWalker()
  walker.walk(listener, tree)
  return listener.array
```

Transposeur.g4:

```
grammar Transposeur;

myfile: block+;

block: title
     | paragraph
     ;

title: firstTitle
     | secondTitle
    ;

firstTitle: '#' ' '? unit+ newline;
secondTitle: '##' ' '? unit+ newline;

paragraph: unit+ newline;

unit: low+
    | upper
    | (low | cap)* cap (low | cap)*
    | ponctuation
    | number
    | space
    ;

upper: cap cap+;
number: digit+;

low: LOW;
cap: CAP;
newline: NEWLINE;
ponctuation: SPACE? PONCT;
space: SPACE;
digit: DIGIT;

LOW: [a-z] | 'ç' | 'é' | 'è' | 'à' | 'â' | 'ê' | 'ù' | 'î' | 'ô' | 'û' | 'ë' | 'ï' | 'ü' | 'œ';
CAP: [A-Z];
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
SPACE: ' ';
DIGIT: [0-9];
PONCT: ',' | '!' | '?' | ';' | '.' | ':';
```

The command that takes time is `tree = parser.myfile()`. Is there any way to make things faster?

Comment: ANTLR is no slouch when it comes to parsing.  A few lines should be nothing even on a "slow" machine.   Is this is "faster" on some other CPU?  What exactly is the text you are feeding to it?

Comment: By symmetry, you write "low+"; why isn't upper simply written as cap+?

Comment: Because un upper should have at least 2 capital letter. On my laptop the same thing runs in less than a second

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it is having trouble resolving the cases **low+** vs  (**low | cap)* ....** where it may have to look arbitrarily far ahead to determine which reduction to apply.

I think the real problem is that your **unit+** reference is ambiguous with respect to **low+**.  Given the text for a unit consisting of:

```
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

(fifty "a"s).  One can parse that with:

- a **unit** having **low+** of all "a"s,
- **unit unit** with first **low+** of any prefix, and the second **low+** of the rest of the "a"s (that's 2500 possibilities)
- **unit unit unit** with a first **low+** of any prefix, a last **low+** of any remaining suffix, and a middle **low+** of the characters in
  between (way, way more possibilities)
- **unit unit unit unit** ...

So I think this part of your grammar is highly ambiguous and ANTLR is exploring the huge space of choices trying to choose one. You are probably
lucky that ANTLR is fast enough to finish at all :-}

You'll have same trouble with **unit+** and **upper** (== **cap+**).

It isn't clear to me how much of the structure of a unit that you really need to capture. It looks to me like you just want a string.
Try recoding it as:

```
unit: low
    | cap
    | ponctuation
    | number
    | space
  ;
```

Even better, define unit this way:

```
unit: LOW | CAP | PONCT | DIGIT | SPACE ;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. All these units need to have their own rule in the listener. I also need to make a distinction between lower, UPPER, an MiXeD words. And a single letter capital word ('A') is counted as a mixed word.

Comment: OK. Using "pure" ANTLR grammar rules is just going to get you this ambiguity nonsense. So either you change how you use ANTLR rules (I'd suggest considerating a semantic action that makes a particular kind of unit give up if another would recognize a string), or push the unit recognition into the lexer, under the assumption that lexical matching has some kind of greedy properties and will look for a longest match. Here's where my knowledge of ANTLR4 falls down; I don't really know what you can write for lexical tokens or if ANTLR has some kind of greedy rule. Most generated lexers have such.